# How to rename `xmlns` as TYPE using C#

Tags: c#, xml

I'm trying to create a XML file format by using c#. Ii almost done. But, the output not yet come as I expect.

my current output is

```
   <?xml version="1.0"?> 
<ArrayOfMESSAGE xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">   
        <MESSAGE>
        <HEADER xmlns="M_DAT">
        </HEADER>
        <DATA_SET>

        </DATA_SET>   
        </MESSAGE> 
   </ArrayOfMESSAGE>
<MSG />
```

program.cs

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("D:\\read.xml", FileMode.Create))
            {
                using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(fs, new XmlWriterSettings() { OmitXmlDeclaration = true, Indent = true }))
                {lstQTM);
                    writer.WriteStartElement("MSG");
                    new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<QTMList>)).Serialize(fs, lstQTMlist);
                    writer.WriteEndElement();
                }
            }
```

QTMList.cs

```
[XmlType("MESSAGE")]
    //[XmlElement("MSG")]
    public class QTMList
    {
        [XmlElement(Namespace = "M_DAT" ,ElementName ="HEADER")]
        public List<QTMMain> QTMMain { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "DATA_SET")]
        public List<QTMdataset> QTMdataset { get; set; }
    }
```

My desire output is

```
<MSG>
<MESSAGE>
<HEADER Type="M_DAT"> 
</HEADER>
<DATA_SET SampleSize="5">
</DATA_SET>
</MESSAGE>
</MSG>
```

how can I change

> xmlns

as TYPE

Please give me some hint

Comment: Please can you clarify your wording.. what does "com" mean? "complete"? "compile"?  Also "don". Thx

Comment: @ChrisWalsh sorry for the spelling mistake. could you please check

Comment: @ArebhySri `xmlns` isn't a type. It's used to specify namespaces. There's nothing wrong with the XML you have right now apart from the mixup between `ArrayOfMESSAGE` and `MSG` which has *nothing* to do with namespaces

Comment: Your code mixes up different XML techniques. It manulally emits some elements but serializes others. The XML you posted shows a `MSG` object that contains an array of `MESSAGE` objects. You tried to serialize a `List<QTMList>` instead, forcing XmlSerializer to create a root object

Comment: I accept xmlns not a type. But, i want to change xmlns as TYPE

Comment: Hi @ArebhySri, I think we're still not understanding by what you mean by "I want to change xmlns as TYPE".  Are you saying you want `<HEADER Type="M_DAT">` to appear instead of (I assume `<HEADER xmlns="M_DAT">`)?  If so, trying to use `[XmlElement(Namespace = "M_DAT"..]` is probably the wrong approach, you need to emit a standard "attribute" node with name="type" and value="M_DAT" but I don't know how you are going to auto-generate the value "M_DAT" from the namespace (if that is what you are hoping to do).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have change my `QTMMain` class as

```
 public class QTMMain
    {
        [XmlAttribute("TYPE")]
        public string TYPE { get; set; }

        [XmlText]
        public string Value { get; set; }
        public string DEVICE_TYPE { get; set; }
        public string DEVICE_ID { get; set; }
        //[XmlType(TypeName = "DEVICE_TYPE")]
        public string SWITCH_ID { get; set; }
        //[XmlType(TypeName = "DATE_TIME")]
        public string DATE_TIME { get; set; }
        public List<QTMStats> QTMStats { get; set; }
        public List<QTM> QTM { get; set; }
}
```

I have added

```
[XmlAttribute("TYPE")]
public string TYPE { get; set; }
[XmlText]
public string Value { get; set; }
```

lines into above class.then it printed as I expect.

Thank you @Chris Walsh sir to give me a hint.